# How can I simplify this code with a loop or function?

Tags: php, wordpress, function, loops

I'm working on my first WordPress theme option from scratch. I have some code like below that fills the empty options if they don't set 'in current send form process'...

(Without this code, if a user sends the form then the other options that aren't in the current view will be clear and their value will be deleted! **This code keeps their values and is working correctly.**)

I just need to simplify this code:

```
if ( empty( $options['index1_status'] ) ) {$options['index1_status'] = get_status('index1_status');}
if ( empty( $options['index2_status'] ) ) {$options['index2_status'] = get_status('index2_status');}
if ( empty( $options['index3_status'] ) ) {$options['index3_status'] = get_status('index3_status');}
if ( empty( $options['index4_status'] ) ) {$options['index4_status'] = get_status('index4_status');}
if ( empty( $options['index5_status'] ) ) {$options['index5_status'] = get_status('index5_status');}
```

How can I simplify this code with a loop or function?

Comment: please add proper tags like which language it was written in ? what it does ? what do you want to achieve. that'll help you get answer sooner

Comment: yes exactly . thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And just add more to the `$optionsArray`

```
$optionsArray = [
    'index1_status',
    'index2_status',
    'index3_status',
    'index4_status',
    'index5_status',
];

foreach ($optionsArray as $v)
{
 // if $options[$v] is empty, then set it to get_status($v), else keep its original value
    $options[$v] = (empty($options[$v])) ? get_status($v) : $options[$v];
}
```